# if pathname starts with, as well as contains . Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, testing

I am trying to test the pathname of the url, checking if pathname starts with privmsg as well as contains one of the words in the selection. And my quantifier is selecting that at least one word must be found.

New RegExp thanks to one of the answers and I extended it more.

```
var post = /(^\/privmsg\?).+(post|reply){1}(.*)?/;
```

My urls will look like

```
/privmsg?mode=post
/privmsg?mode=reply
/privmsg?mode=reply&p=2 //another way
```

Though we have other modes that I do not want. I need to just get the constant url beginning with privmsg and having at least post or reply in it. Can someone explain what is wrong with my regex string and if I used the quantifier incorrectly.

Problem now is that it is still coming out false...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow for arbitrary characters between `?` and `(post|reply)` (i.e. `mode=`). E.g.:

```
var post = /^\/privmsg\?.+(post|reply){1}/g;
                        \/
                 |match any sequence of|
                 |1 or more characters |
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate that both the answers actually understood what I was saying lol. I'll check off my accepted answer once tested. Thanks again

Comment: @EasyBB: Talking about documentation: I have found **[this regex resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)** to be invaluable (should anyone care)

Comment: ok sorry for this later, I had to unmark the answer as it was incorrect for me. I tooks yours and added to it, didn't realize that there would be more characters after post and reply sometimes... this is what I have so far yet I keep getting false testing location.pathname   `/(^\/privmsg\?).+(post|reply){1}(.*)?/`

Comment: nevermind location.pathname + location.search was the issue here not just location.pathame

Answer (score 1):

You miss to include something for `mode=`.

With your regex you will match strings like `/privmsg?post`.

So alter your regex to include `mode=`:

```
^\/privmsg\?.*(post|reply)$
```

Comment: Thanks not very fluent in regex as I teach myself everything as I go. And there really is no clean cut documentation to easily learn this. Thanks again

Comment: @EasyBB Glad i could help. Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most.